# Display text in order in which a checbox is checked using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

**I have a form containing a list of checkboxes. I wish to display some text corresponding to each check box in the order of selection of the check box in another block.And when I deselect a checkbox that text should disappear and if I reselect it it should appear below the existing text. I already checked though many questions in this site. Everywhere there's explanation for the text to appear but not in the order in which the checkbox is checked rather in the order of the checkboxes themselves. I want to do this using html and jquery. Any help towards the direction would be appreciable **

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jinal1482/Lfuzkkvz/

You can replace 'a' and 'b' with your value or you can retrieve value by other attribute as well.

Html code :

```
<input type='checkbox' onclick="updateList('a',this)" />
<input type='checkbox' onclick="updateList('b',this)" />
```

Javascript code :

```
var options = [];
function updateList(obj,source){
    if($(source).attr('checked')){
        options.push(obj);
    }
    else{
        options= $.grep(options, function( a ) {
              return a !== obj;
          });
    }
    console.log(options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple [example](http://jsfiddle.net/r4n55y6v/):

**HTML**:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Apple">Apple</input>
<input type="checkbox" value="Banana">Banana</input>
<input type="checkbox" value="Mango">Mango</input>
<input type="checkbox" value="Orange">Orange</input>
<input type="checkbox" value="Grape">Grape</input>
<ul></ul>
```

**JavaScript (jQuery)**:

```
$("input").on("change", function (e) {
    $("ul").html("");
    $("input:checked").each(function () {
        $("ul").append("<li>" + this.value + "</li>");
    });
});
```

Given the details in the OP this should be what you're looking for. Basically when one of the inputs (checkboxes) `change`, we update our list by looping through each `checked` input. Depending on what you actually want the text to be you would need to modify this example. For each input I would consider putting the text you want to display when an input is clicked in a `data attribute`. Something like:

`<input type="checkbox" value="Apple" data-text="Apples are yummy">Apple</input>`

That way in the loop you could grab each inputs `data-text` attribute and display that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `id` tag and attribute `data-id` with the same value in order to connect checkbox and text

http://jsfiddle.net/edobs5cf/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="checkbox_div">
    <input type='checkbox' data-id="#txt-1" />text 1<br/>
    <input type='checkbox' data-id="#txt-2" />text 2<br/>
    <input type='checkbox' data-id="#txt-3" />text 3<br/>
    <input type='checkbox' data-id="#txt-4" />text 4<br/>
</div>
<div id="text">
    <div id="txt-1">text 1</div>
    <div id="txt-2">text 2</div>
    <div id="txt-3">text 3</div>
    <div id="txt-4">text 4</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#text div{display:none}
```

**JQ:**

```
$('#checkbox_div input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
    var $ch = $(this);
    var $id = $ch.data('id');
    if ($ch.is(':checked')) {
        // ensures that the text appears at the end of the list
        $($id).appendTo($('#text'));
        $($id).show();
    } else $($id).hide();

})
```